# Why do I get an infinite for loop for int 9?

Tags: java, for-loop

Background is described in the end.

In short, why does the following foor loop work for yearInt 0-8 but when the yearInt varliable is a 9 the loop becomes endless?

```
     int yearInt = 9;//scanned year - for testing        
    int currentYearFourNumbers = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year

    currentYearFourNumbers = 2023; // for testing!! 

   int currentYearLastDigit=currentYearFourNumbers%10; //mod operator for getting last digit of current year 
    int resultYear = currentYearFourNumbers;    //init int result which will represent the identified year 
    int checkNumber = currentYearLastDigit; //counter or check number for for loop

       for (int i = yearInt; i != checkNumber; checkNumber--){

           checkNumber = resultYear%10;
            System.out.println (checkNumber);
            System.out.println (i);
           resultYear = resultYear -1; 
           System.out.println (resultYear);
       }
```

If I have a 8 it works see output:

check:3
against8
2022
check:2
against8
2021
check:1
against8
2020
check:0
against8
2019
check:9
against8
2018
Manufacture date2018

Background:

I need create logic to determine which year should be entered into a database based on one digit. 
The digit is part of a scanned serial number from a device and represent manufacturing year.

The digit 4 should right now represent 2004 but next year it should represent 2014. 
The logic should work in 2020 as well so I need a "permament" solution.

I therefor created a foor loop that takes the scanned digit and compares it to the last digit of current year. I then subtract (devices can not have futured date) a year at the time until last digit of the year is same as the scanned year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets have a look here:

```
for (int i = yearInt; i != checkNumber; checkNumber--){
     checkNumber = resultYear%10;
     System.out.println (checkNumber);// In here you are just giving it the initial value again.
     System.out.println (i);
     resultYear = resultYear -1; 
     System.out.println (resultYear);
}
```

So your loop will execute while `i != checkNumber`, and `checkNumber` is decremented on every iteration. But what if `checkNumber < i` to begin with? That's where your infinite loop comes from. If `i > checkNumber` from the start, `checkNumber` will never be `== i`.

In your case, `checkNumber` is `3`. Your loop should probably have `i--` not `checkNumber--`

For a simpler solution:

```
public static int getFinalYear(int digit) {
    int year = 2013;
    int finalYear = year;
    int lastYear = year % 10;
    if (digit > lastYear) {
        finalYear += (digit - lastYear) - 10;
    } else {
        finalYear -= lastYear - digit;
    }
    return finalYear;
}
```

It's not thoroughly tested, but have a look.

```
System.out.println(getFinalYear(1));// 2011
System.out.println(getFinalYear(2));// 2012
System.out.println(getFinalYear(3));// 2013
System.out.println(getFinalYear(4));// 2004
System.out.println(getFinalYear(5));// 2005
System.out.println(getFinalYear(6));// 2006
System.out.println(getFinalYear(7));// 2007
System.out.println(getFinalYear(8));// 2008
System.out.println(getFinalYear(9));// 2009
```

Comment: Thank for input! If checknumber (i.e. the last number of current year = 3 in your example) is smaller than yearInt (digit=8 in your example) then 8 is checked against 2 (from 2012) 1 (from 2011) 0 (from 2010) 9 (from 2009) and the 8 (from 2008) and then I get 2008 which I want. And I do get 2008 in my loop but I dont get 2009. Try it, its weird!!

Comment: In your example if i have digit= 2 I will get 2014 not 2012.

Answer (score 1):

In java, the increament/decreament statement (in your case `checkNumber--`) is always evaluated before condition statement except for the first iteration.

In your case, when checkNumber is `9` inside the for loop, it is decremented to `8` before comparing.

Something like this should work in your case-

```
for (int i = yearInt; i != checkNumber;){
  checkNumber = resultYear%10;
  System.out.println (checkNumber);
  System.out.println (i);
  resultYear = resultYear -1; 
  System.out.println (resultYear);
  if(checkNumber==0){//whenever checknumber is 0, it should be set to 9 
    checkNumber=9;
  }else{
    checkNumber--;
  }
}
```

Above is just an example to avoid infinte loop. You might need to modify the code further as per your business requirements.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm just a Little confused since it works with an 8 and not a nince. See my updated question.

Comment: ur code didn't worked for 9 because when checkNumber is `0` and u do `checkNumber--`, your checkNumber becomes `-1`. So when checkNumber is `0` u will need to manually set it to `9` instead of doing `checkNumber--`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't noticed how a for loop works.

According to the Java tutorial at [Orcale.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

> The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop.

This is how your code works,
In each for iteration , the for statement decreases checkNumber. I have debugged and saw when i is 9 and checkNumber is 9 the for should terminates but for statement first decreases chechNumber then process the criteria.

I have changed your code to code below and it solved the infinite problem.

```
// the value of checkNumber should check before decrement! 
for (int i = yearInt; i != checkNumber --; ){

    checkNumber = resultYear%10;
    System.out.println (checkNumber);
    System.out.println (i);
    resultYear = resultYear -1;
    System.out.println (resultYear);
}
```

I hope it helped :)

Comment: This gives me a 8 for a 9 and a 7 for a 8 but no infinite loop so I like that. It still doesn't answer why my loops works with an 8 but not with a 9.

Comment: @djcj
I told you, your code was wrong and and accidentally it was working fine with other numbers.